# HDMI input in laptop through USB 3.1 type c or USB A 3.0

Tags: video, usb, video-capture, data-transfer, hdmi

My laptop: HP Probook 450
I've got this HDMI Dongle which is basically a retro game that you normally plug into your TV and play off there. link: https://www.jaycar.com.au/2-controller-wireless-retro-arcade-game-console-with-638-games/p/GT4282

What I want to do: I want to use my laptop as a "monitor". Basically if I'm ever out and bored, I can plug this game into my laptop and play. Thats the idea

my laptop has:
HDMI Port
USB 3.1 type c port
USB A 3.0 port
(amongst others).

The game won't work directly by plugging it into the HDMI Port due to lack of a video capture card and also I'm fairly certain its only HDMI out.

Now I bought the video capture card adapter thing, where its one end HDMI female and the other end is USB type C. And this is where I messed up. When I plug it into the type C port, nothing happens. I hear a little "ding" ( like something has been connected) but nothing shows up. and when i go to my display setting to manually detect a display, nothing comes up.

after reading online I think, the type-C port on my laptop is actually only Video out (correct me if I'm wrong).

So my question is, how do I do this. How can I use my laptop as a monitor of sorts and is it possible for my laptop to accept video rather than output it. I was thinking of getting usb 3.1 type C socket to USB A 3.0 plug adapter, but thought I should probably ask first

Answer (score 0):

figured it out.
So with the exact setup i have above: The game plugged into the vid capture card and plugged into my computer, all i have to do is go to my camera app and click the camera icon which scans for other cameras. To which the game video is picked up as a 'camera' and works well enough. only downside is no audio